# Cannot start two emulators at the same time

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I am having a problem with Android emulator.

I have two avd:

- Android2:

[image]

- Android4

[image]

1. Now, I suppose Android4 is running.
2. When I start Android2, "Starting Android Emulator" dialog is displayed then nothing happens (it means Android2 is not running).
3. If I close Android4, and run it again, it doesn't run, yet it Android2 which I start before, run instead.

Could any one help with this problem?

Please leave me comment if this question is not clear.

Comment: Can you post your `Android Console`?

Comment: Try to start emulators with shell script.

Comment: less CPU configuration may be the cause.

Comment: @rIHaNJiTHiN nothing in the console.

Comment: @Yahor10 I already tried it. Nothing happens.

Comment: @LeapBun: nothing?? are you sure its `android console`? may be you were looking at the `DDMS` console.

Comment: post both AVD details of the emulator.

Comment: @hotveryspicy how to change CPU configueration?

Comment: @LeapBun: What's your system configuration. May be your machine is lacking required resources to run two instances of emulators

Comment: @Mahendra I think my machine capacity is enough (CPU: Core 2 Duo, RAM: 4GB).

Answer (score 0):

First run your proj in android2 avd once it is started..Then goto your project package in eclipse right click->properties->android->change project build target to 4.0 => apply->ok
Now again run your project it will definetly start your another avd [android4]..

Hope this help you. :-)

Comment: Try to change your android:minSdkVersion="15" in AndroiManifest.xml after you have started android2 and then again run your app.

Answer (score 0):

Set the GPU Emulation to "YES" in AVD MANAGER properties..